# Hide Minimize Button in Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way (using C#) to hide and disable the minimize/close button?

I have a form that I use for login, and I would just rather they not be able to close the window.

Failing hiding the button, is there a way to catch that it was pressed and ignore/re-direct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the BorderStyle to None and make it the size of the screen.  You can optionally draw in a "caption" area manually to make it look like there is a caption.

Comment: I liked the idea, but the title bar (and it's minimize button) are still shown.  My form (now full screen) is under it.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working:

```
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
this.ControlBox = false;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

It got rid of the whole title bar, but that is ok for my purposes.